# Trying to use an ESP32 to collect data from a capacitive soil moisture sensor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-3.7, esp32

I am trying to use my ESP32 to collect data from a HW-390 Capacitive Soil Moisture Sensor to be used as part of an automated sprinkler system. I am unsure of how to program data collection from the sensor in python for my ESP32. I am using a raspberry pi 4 to write the code in Thonny IDE (If I need to change anything let me know).
Does anyone know what I need to write in python3.7 (or another version if necessary) to receive the data on my Raspberry Pi 4 and collect the data on the ESP32 from the soil moisture sensor?

Comment: what is the problem? sensor has analogue output. here are example how you can interface it  - [code and schematics](https://www.faranux.com/product/capacitive-soil-moisture-sens31/). I believe that both code and schematics are applicable to esp32 because operating voltage is 3.3-5.5V

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny The website you linked has code written for an arduino and I don't understand how to apply that code to my ESP32. I know how to copy python files onto the ESP32 and run them however I don't know how I could use the arduino code.

Comment: here is how to [read analogue signals by python at esp32](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/quickref.html#adc-analog-to-digital-conversion)

Comment: Thank you @MaximSagaydachny, you've been very helpful.